# append new data in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

i have specific question...

my JSON structue

```
{"Math":[
    {   "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some txt",
        "subtitle2" : "some txt",
        "id": "1",
        "date":"08J", 
        "question":"some txt",
        "ans01": "some txt1",
        "ans02": "some txt2",
        "ans03": "some txt3",
        "ans04": "some txt4",
        "ans05": "some txt5",
        "correct": "some txt2",
        "ans01count": 0, 
        "ans02count": 0, 
        "ans03count": 0, 
        "ans04count": 0, 
        "ans05count": 0  
         }, 
         { same as above couple times}], 
"Psychic":[
    {   "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some txt",
        "subtitle2" : "some txt",
        "id": "1",
        "date":"08J", 
        "question":"some txt",
        "ans01": "some txt1",
        "ans02": "some txt2",
        "ans03": "some txt3",
        "ans04": "some txt4",
        "ans05": "some txt5",
        "correct": "some txt2",
        "ans01count": 0, 
        "ans02count": 0, 
        "ans03count": 0, 
        "ans04count": 0, 
        "ans05count": 0  
         }, 
         { same as above couple times}]
```

That's how i open json file:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('../question.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

That's the way to add/edit some data:

```
// $tit = title as on example 'Math'
$data[$tit][$idnum]['question'] = $quest;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['ans01'] = $ans1;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['ans02'] = $ans2;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['ans03'] = $ans3;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['ans04'] = $ans4;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['ans05'] = $ans5;
$data[$tit][$idnum]['correct'] = $corr;

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('../question.json', $newJsonString);
```

but, i can add data only if index ($idnum) not exist, my question is:
How do add data for example in middle. My code can only edit for example question with index nr. 10. but can't add question with index 10 and push all next questions(question with index 10 need to be 11 and etc.). my json data have 70k lines of code. 20 main topics...

Comment: _"my json data have 70k lines of code"_ I think it's time to start looking at databases...

Comment: we we will go for database soon, but not now. We will rebuild whole project, but for now we need it working as fast as possible.

Comment: also we are using new stdClass(); and array_unshift(); that's allow as for add data on beginning only...

Comment: Maybe use `array_slice()` to split the array into two chunks, add your new item to the end of the first, then use `array_merge()` to put them back together.

Comment: Or maybe `array_splice()` but I'm not sure the "remove a portion" part can be zero items.

Comment: Ah yeah here you go, from `array_splice()`: _"If length is specified and is zero, no elements will be removed"_

Comment: i will try thanks for a clue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a new item at a certain location in an existing array, you can use `array_splice()` with 0 for the third argument:

```
$existingArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$newItem = ['title' => 'Foo', 'id' => 'bar', ... ];
array_splice($existingArray[$title], $newPosition, 0, [$newItem]);
```

`$existingArray` will now contain `$newItem` inserted at position `$newPosition`.

Note that this will *not* change the value of your `id` elements, you'll have to do that yourself if desired.